# <iframe> is not working

Tags: html, iframe

I'm making a simple html page which is require an `<iframe>` to show a specific area of the page. I used iframe so many times but this time I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Please take a look at my code and help me!

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Iframe Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://www.secure-booker.com/sorelle/ShopOnline/Products.aspx" width="1000" height="1000" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "is not working" mean?

Comment: IS NOT WORKING mean that iframe is not working and showing nothing...

Comment: Its blocked by X-FRAME-OPTIONS. Refer my answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you are trying to embed in the iframe blocks itself from being embedded.

You can see this if you open your browser's console (F12) and select the "Console" tab.

```
Refused to display 'https://www.secure-booker.com/sorelle/ShopOnline/Products.aspx' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' http://*.sorellechicago.com sorellechicago.com *.sorellechicago.com".
```

TL;DR: It's not possible.

Comment: Is there any alternative way?

Comment: Nope. Not that I know of. Sorry.

Comment: Although try googling "circumvent xframe options" and you find articles such as this: https://blog.elev.io/getting-around-the-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin-issue/ I can't claim to have read it though.

Comment: It didn't work Jack but thanks for the information and the knowledge :)

Comment: Yep a shame ... But at least I know a new thing... Jack what does TL;DR mean?

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to iFrame this Website. because they have set the following.

> 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

You can find this from your console.

> Refused to display 'https://www.secure-booker.com/sorelle/ShopOnline/Products.aspx' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' http://*.sorellechicago.com sorellechicago.com *.sorellechicago.com".

#### How to set this options?

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options
2. [How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)
3. [X-Frame-Options on apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092154/x-frame-options-on-apache)

> One more note (FYI) : AFAIK, there is one more thing called `Frame Buster Code` to prevent other domain to iFrame the site. Below is the reference URLs:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller
2. https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-framebuster
3. [Frame Buster Buster ... buster code needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed)

Its a part of `Clickjacking` as well. Refer the below URL as well.
1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking