# X-Frame-Options Header Not Set: How do I set it?

Tags: php, apache, security, x-frame-options, x-content-type-options

I am using Apache server for Wamp application. While doing security testing, I got these error reports which says:

1. **X-Frame-Options Header Not Set.**
   For this I know that there are 3 types of X-Frame Options. But where do I implement the SAMEORIGIN option and how?
2. **X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing.**

What do I need to do to solve these?
Thank you.

Comment: You can set these in your Apache config files.  One note of warning: If you use e.g. Adsense ads  doing as suggested by security advidories will break your ads completely.

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig Sorry I'm new to this, would you mind explaining what is Adsense ads? By the way, do I set it in any lines of my Apache config files?

Comment: Adsense is a platform for serving ads from Google to monetize your website. Be very careful with Apache configuration options like this because they can break everything! I did this once and returned little later to the original state as I had a lot of problems.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the advice! I'll be sure to take note of it. :)

Comment: Please also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092154/x-frame-options-on-apache

Comment: Note: If you have this WAMP server in your local network or at localhost and it will not be reachable from the Internet, forget the security warnings. If it is a public server on the Internet, there are far more dangers than that.

Comment: @Nicole take a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following headers:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-options: nosniff
```

Since you are using Apache, add the following to the apache config:

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
```

The above won't do anything for a local test server. But, you should always set them in public production servers.

**Remember:** Even though it doesn't do anything for local servers, you could develop your website with this environment, so that it doesn't suffer when you release it on production.

Comment: Do I add these to any line of my apache config?

Comment: @Nicole yes. make sure mod_headers is enabled

Comment: Sorry, how do I know if mod_headers is enabled?

Comment: @Nicole In your httpd.conf, you should remove the `#` from the line saying: `#LoadModule headers_module ....` And restart apache]

Comment: @Nicole let me know if that is enough.

Comment: Hi, it managed to work. Thank you very much. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using Apache, add the following to the apache config:

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
```

Works perfect!